# Ceph: HEALTH_WARN clock skew detected

Tags: centos, ntp, ntpd, ntpdate, ceph

I have configured ntp on Ceph nodes and time is synchronized! But *ceph status* always shows clock skew.

```
ceph health detail shows:
mon.node2 aadr 192.168.56.102:6789/0 clock skew 7192.45s > max 0.05s (latency 0.0129368s)
mon.node3 aadr 192.168.56.103:6789/0 clock skew 7192.46s > max 0.05s (latency 0.00915873s)
```

How to force Ceph to update status? All time on nodes are equal! If I execute date command on all nodes then it shows correct and same time. But Ceph thinks that time is skewed on 7192.45s!

It is my configuration on nodes /etc/ntp.conf:

```
driftfile /vat/lib/ntp/drift

restrict 0.0.0.0 mask 0.0.0.0

server 0.ua.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 1.ua.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 2.ua.pool.ntp.org iburst
server 3.ua.pool.ntp.org iburst

includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
disable monitor
```

It is my /etc/rc.local on nodes:

```
touch /var/lock/subsys/local
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/sysconfig/iptables
/sbin/ntpd -gq
/sbin/hwclock --systohc
systemctl enable ntpd.service
systemctl start ntpd.service
```

*systemctl status ntpd.service* shows that service is active and running.

In addition some strange things happens with ceph if I put peers in /etc/ntp.conf. Ceph becomes unresponsible and *ceph -s* shows nothing (it freezes).

Please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but it have happened because of command in `ntpd-gq`. This command updates your datatime from servers which you have written in ntp.conf and then stops.
I can't figure out why ceph fails after this command but when I changed it to:

```
ntpdate 0.ua.pool.ntp.org
```

Ceph became work.